# gRPC: How to get multiple return values in Java client with Go server

Tags: java, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I have a `protocol buffer` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package v1api;
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "myApp.v1";
option java_outer_classname = "V1";

service API {
    rpc Login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse)
}

message LoginRequest {
    int pin = 1
}

message LoginResponse {
    string token = 1
}
```

I have my server written in Go (a language that can return multiple values), and my client being an Android application.

When I use this protoBuf to generate Go code for server, it is something like:

```
...
func (c *aPIClient) Login(ctx context.Context, in *LoginRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*LoginResponse, error) {
    out := new(LoginResponse)
    err := grpc.Invoke(ctx, "/v1api.API/Login", in, out, c.cc, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
...
```

Notice that there are **two** return values, `(*LoginResponse, error)`.

Now, when I use this protoBuf to generate Java code for my Android side, I get something like:

```
public myApp.v1.LoginResponse login(myApp.v1.LoginRequest request) {
    return blockingUnaryCall(getChannel(), METHOD_LOGIN, getCallOptions(), request);
}
```

Notice that, here, there is just **one** return value like Java allows, `myApp.v1.LoginResponse`.

My question is, in case of an error returned by the server (something like: `return nil, err`), how will I get that second return value in my Android side.

Comment: As an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, the error returned by your `Login` method will get converted into the wire format status `code` and `message` used by gRPC.  In your case, if you return a  [status.Status](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/status), the Code and message will be sent and show up on the Java side as a [StatusRuntimeException](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/StatusRuntimeException.html).  If you return a non `Status` error, gRPC will convert it to the `UNKNOWN` code, but preserve the message.

This is the reason there are two return values for Go, vs. just one for Java.  Java can "return" a secondary value by throwing an exception in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java does not support multiple return values, when a protoBuf is generated into a java code, the errors are communicated by throwing exceptions. Make your gRPC call in a `try-catch` block and catch any `StatusRuntimeException` that the call may throw.